# What's the difference between 舟 and 船?

Tags: words, meaning, nuances, homophonic-kanji

They both mean "ship/boat".  Are they completely interchangeable?  Do they signify boats of different sizes or uses (people, cargo, etc.)?  Is only `船` used in compounds to describe metaphorical "boats" of abstract usage, like `[風船]{ふう・せん}`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The interchangeability between [舟]{ふね} and [船]{ふね} , in theory, is close to non-existent.  In real life, however, it is left to the judgement of each individual.  Generally speaking, the more educated or well-read you are, the less interchangeable the two will become.

In school, we are taught to use 舟 to refer to a small boat, usually (but not necessarily) hand-rowed.  船 refers to a larger boat than a 舟. For this, 船 can be used for a much wider variety of boat sizes.  It is all about the physical size, not the purpose of the boat (passengers. cargo, etc.).

Metaphorically, both 舟 and 船 are used as well.

舟：[助け舟]{たすけぶね} = "timely help or support",  [舟]{ふね} = "a small boat-shaped dish on which foods (like takoyaki and sashimi) are served", etc.

船：[飛行船]{ひこうせん} = "blimp", [宇宙船]{うちゅうせん} = "spaceship", etc.

Comment: そうなら、「小舟」と「小船」はどれだけのもの？